# pubsub tutorial change string

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i successfully ran the pubsub Tutorial. [This Q](http://answers.ros.org/question/12163/talker-issue-on-android-pubsub-tutorial/) helped me to see the message in RQT on my Computer.

How can i change the  text hello world?

```
rosTextView.setMessageToStringCallable ((message) -> {return message.getData();});
```

what is this doing exactly?

when executing the Talker, how does the node know what to publish?

```
nodeMainExecuter.execute(talker, nodeConfiguration)
```

Edit:

Thanks for your short explanation.

---

Edit:

in rosjava - tutorial pubsub i can change the talker.java

Then i do

```
cd rosjava_core-hydro
./gradlew install
```

This builds the new libraries.
Now i have my lib in

```
home/user/rosjava_core-hydro/build/libs
```

i think i ve installed rosjava like [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/hydro/Installation)

The referenced libs in the android project are in

```
opt/ros/hydro/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_core/    .../rosjava_tutorial_pubsub
```

How do i get my libs to this root-folder?

Edit:
in my android project i can change the root of this lib in

```
.idea/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub_0_1_6.xml 

root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/rosjava_core-hydro/build/libs/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub-0.1.6.jar!/"
```

still saying hello world

---

---

Final Edit:

Changing something in talker.class in your rosjava

where do i have to do catkin_make or ./gradle install ???? to create the lib

Then using nautilus with sudo to copy the generated lib into the root folder

```
opt/ros/hydro/share/maven/org/ros/rosjava_core/    .../rosjava_tutorial_pubsub
```

here exchange the -jar through your new .jar (with talker and listener class) in it

And now the app publishes the text you wrote in the talker.java file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188778/pubsub-tutorial-change-string/) by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on 2014-08-05**:
maybe someone can extend the pubsub tutorial with a section for changing the text of "hello world" to my custom text - could be useful

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-05**:
@stefan: changing it should not have been so involved. All that should be needed is to build the rosjava repository from source, and have your ros android projects depend on that, instead of overwriting binary dists in '/opt/ros/..'.

**Comment by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on 2014-08-05**:
maybe i got smthing wrong with rosandroid and rosjava folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you haven't already, I suggest you read through the available [ros java documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava). Especially the [rosjava_core documentation](http://rosjava.github.io/rosjava_core/hydro/index.html) should be helpful. The java ROS client and interaction works a little different from the other client libraries (such as `roscpp` and `rospy`).

Both your questions should be answered after this.

---

Edit: for completeness:

> what is this doing exactly?

```
rosTextView.setMessageToStringCallable ((message) -> {return message.getData();});
```

This is most likely a 'collapsed' view of (so your editor is collapsing this, look for a 'plus' in the gutter or margin):

```
rosTextView.setMessageToStringCallable(new MessageCallable<String, std_msgs.String>() {
  @Override
  public String call(std_msgs.String message) {
    return message.getData();
  }
});
```

In short: the class `RosTextView` extends a specialised `View`, which can update (append) its contents whenever a message comes in over a certain topic (in this case *chatter*, set by invoking `rosTextView.setTopicName("chatter")`). The method `setMessageToStringCallable(..)` just registers a callback (anonymous `MessageCallable` here) which will be invoked upon reception of a message. In this case it just returns the data within the message (which is a `String`), which `RosTextView` will use to update its view.

Your other questions can also be answered by reading the sources of the relevant classes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1